# Standard template library for segment tree

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any STL for segment tree ? Else can we achieve it using any other library function ? i want to know because it can reduce our time to a greater extent during programming contests !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such thing in STL, but there is a Boost library called [Interval Container Library (ICL)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) which is basically an implementation of the data structure you are looking for.